# Multiple factories inside parent factory

Tags: java, design-patterns, abstract-factory

As you can see in the picture below [image: entity factory class diagram]I have a factory pattern that creates entities at runtime. As I was studying my database, I decided that there is a student and a professor that "ISA" Person, because they have some fields in common (like name and prename).

Likewise, I decided that there are abiding and deputy professors that "ISA" Professor.

In the runtime, the user selects entities like "Professor", "Student", etc. Not Person. So in this case I have to create new Professor, Student etc entities. Likewise, when the user selects Professor entity, it has to decide which type of Professor wants to create.

The code for the factory I created so far is like

```
public class EntityFactory {
protected String entityType;

public EntityFactory(String personType){
    this.entityType = entityType;
}

public Entity createEntity(){
    if(entityType.equalsIgnoreCase("Student")){
        return new Student();
    }
    else if(entityType.equalsIgnoreCase("Professor")){
        return new Professor();
    }
    //...
}
}
```

I am wondering: How can I "pass over" Person and Professor abstract entities to create the specific entity I want? Is that feasable? Or do I need to create different factories for the entities I set as abstract? And how am I going to link those factories with the "parent" factory it such case?

Comment: What's the point of this factory in the first place? If I want to create a new Student, why would I call the type-unsafe `Student s = (Student) factory.create("Student")` instead of simply doing `Student s = new Student()`?

Comment: because I don't know what entity the user will select in runtime to be created. There are plenty of entities, not just those 2.

Comment: @VassilisDe that doesn't answer @JBNizet's question. Where/why is the `Person` type needed in the first place ? Why do you need this abstraction ? If you just have common fields in `Professor` and `Student`, better IMO to group those in reusable value objects (`Address`, `Name`, etc) than blindly jump at that opportunity to create a base class.

Comment: @guillaume31 I'm not sure I get exactly what you mean by IMO...

Comment: @VassilisDe [www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=imo](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=imo) ;)

Comment: Ok! :-) I might follow your suggestion in this case. The above conception was just closer to my logic.

Answer (score 1):

To be perfectly honest I am not sure whether I understand your question correctly.

*Part 1: You want to "pass" on creating `Person` or `Professor` entities since they are abstract, i.e. they don't really exist in the database and just serve the purpose of base classes.*

One thing I could think of would be to prevent the user of your factory from requesting these entity types, by using an `enum` instead of a `String` to identify the `entityType`. This `enum` would only contain things that can actually be created, i.e. not `Person` or `Professor`.

*Part 2: Or do I need to create different factories for the entities I set as abstract? And how am I going to link those factories with the "parent" factory it such case?*

You don't technically need to create separate factories, it should depend on how complex the creation of those objects is. If it is complex, then you should split it up if it cannot be generalized.

The way you could split this up into multiple factories (or something similar) is to use a strategy pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) that uses the requested `entityType` as the context to select a strategy to use -- the strategy could be a specialized factory for that specific type.

If your `Person` and `Professor` types are really *abstract* in the Java sense, then you can't instantiate them which means it would not be possible to have *parent factories*. I guess you could probably implement everything inside the constructor of `Person` or use an initialization method of some sort.

Hope this might move you a step forward :)

***Update: A first step would be to use a `switch` statement with the enum values in your creation method***

```
public enum EntityType {
    STUDENT,
    ABIDING_PROF,
    DEPUTY_PROF

    // ...
}

public class EntityFactory {
    private final EntityType entityType;

    public EntityFactory(EntityType entityType) {
        this.entityType = entityType;
    }

    public Entity createEntity() {
        switch (entityType) {
            case STUDENT:
                return new Student(); // or some more sophisticated construction logic

            case DEPUTY_PROF:
                return new DeputyProfessor(); // .. or something else

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you need to map what a user enters into the user interface at some place to the enum values, but that should be easily doable and you could use an appropriate UI component that disallows wrong types (let's say a combobox that only contains whats allowed).

Comment: the enums might do to me. If I understood well what you mean, I have to create an `enum = {Student, Abiding_prof, Deputy_prof}`. I have to admit that I don't know much about enums...how would I change the `creatEentity()` method in order to work with enum?

Comment: I've updated my original post due to the formatting not really working in comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems for me like you do **not** need a factory here in the first place. Think of it as creation **strategies** based upon given precondition: there must exist a level (probably your UI), where user specifies explicity what he or she wants. So all yoy need is different implementation of a `() -> Entity` function (C# version is `Entity Create() {}`). There are two common ways to solve such problem: either `AbstractFactory` - a factory of factories, a higher order factory, or plain-old `Strategy` pattern (which also goes well with `State` pattern, where actual state is selection made by user).

No matter how, eventually you would get to the `() -> Entity` signature, even if it would be explicitly defined in your code. Seems like `Func<Entity>` or `Func<Task<Entity>>` is the most compact yet reusable & testable type. Though, custom `IEnitityBuilder` would work as well.